Polars Expression Chaining with Dynamic Number Operations
When dealing with dynamic number of operations, especially with calculations depending on previous steps, the Polars Expression chaining becomes tricky:
here is a demo operator to generate new variables:
def demo_operator_addition(var1: str, var2: str) -> IntoExpr:
    return pl.col(var1).add(pl.col(var2))

The above Callable is then used in the helper function:
def variable_calculation(
        data: pl.DataFrame,
        target_var: str,
        operator: Callable,
        reference_var: Optional[str] = None,
        by: Optional[List[str]] = None,
        col_name: Optional[str] = None,
        ) -> pl.DataFrame:
    
    data = data.lazy()
    by = by if by is not None else []

    data = (
        data
        .with_columns(
            operator(target_var, reference_var)
            .over([True, *by])
            .alias(col_name) if col_name is not None else target_var
            )
        )
    
    return data.collect()

I want to be able to use variable_calculation function dynamically with different operations:
operation1 = variable_calculation(
    df,
    target_var="var1",
    reference_var="var2",
    operator=demo_operator_addition,
    col_name="var3",
    )

operation2 = variable_calculation(
    operation1,
    target_var="var1",
    reference_var="var3",
    operator=demo_operator_addition,
    col_name="var4",
    )

In the above operations var3 is generated before var4, which requires var3 to calculate. However Polars only allows df.with_columns(calculate var3).with_columns(calculate var4)
Is there an efficient way to dynamically chain those expressions together? (For example, I want to avoid doing operation = xxx definition steps)

Are you asking is it possible to do this without multiple .with_columns calls? Also, do you know about the pipe methods? They're to help with chaining custom functionality e.g. df.pipe(var_calc, x=1, y=2).pipe(var_calc, x=3, y=4)

Yes I am aware of the pipe method. I am looking for a way to chain those operations in a robust setup：for example, df.pipe([operation1, operation2]) where operation 2 depends on the new variable generated using operaion1

What about defining variable_calculation as
def variable_calculation(
    data: pl.DataFrame,
    inputs = List[Tuple[str, Callable, str| None, List[str]|None, str|None]]
    ) -> pl.DataFrame:

    for target_var, operator, reference_var, by, col_name in inputs:
        by = by if by is not None else []
        data = data.lazy()
        

        data = (
            data
            .with_columns(
                operator(target_var, reference_var)
                .over([True, *by])
                .alias(col_name) if col_name is not None else target_var
                )
            ).collect()
        
    return data

then you could do
variable_calculation(
    df,
    [
        ("var1", "var2", demo_operator_addition, "var3"),
        ("var1", "var3", demo_operator_addition, "var4"),
    ],
)

You could change inputs to take an inner dict instead of tuple if you want to use parameter names instead of argument order.
